# How do I make a transparent background for a PNG image in IE6?

Tags: html, scripting, png

How do I make a transparent background for a PNG image in IE6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a solution here with SuperSleight:

http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6

You can use like jquery pluging too:

http://allinthehead.com/retro/338/supersleight-jquery-plugin

Answer (score 1):

the most common way to fix this for png32 is to use fixes like the following:

http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/

http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6

or you could try to use png8 if it the transparancy doesn't include half transparent area's. the result with png8 isn't that smooth though

Answer (score 0):

check it out

```
http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/
```

or

```
http://www.komodomedia.com/blog/2007/11/css-png-image-fix-for-ie/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use alpha-transparency and do not need more than 256 colors - you can try to save your image as 8-bit-png file with additional alpha-channel.

Here's a good explanation:
http://www.ethanandjamie.com/blog/37-user-interface/81-png8-transparency-without-fireworks

The funny thing is that IE6 will ignore the alpah-channel. Other (newer) browsers like Firefox, Opera, IE7+, Chrome, and Safari will try to display the image using the alpha-channel.

I prefer to use this solution because it does not require CSS hacks or Javascript.